# PHP syntax: What does the "?=" mean?

Tags: php

I have the following code , but I'm not understand it:

```
<option value="<?=$beauty_header_font?>"><?=str_replace("+"," ",$beauty_header_font)?></option>
...
```

Help me to clear this,
Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

`<?= $a ?>` is a shorthand for `<?php echo $a; ?>`

(that is the case for php at least)